# Registering and authenticating new app user over api

Tags: android, .net, api, authentication

I have an Android app that connects to a .Net  `api` for receiving/setting data. The confusion that I have is regarding how to signup/login the user first time and authenticate it every time he makes a request to the api.

- If I just use `username/password` based authentication would that be
  safe enough? And should I save that `username/password` in the device
  for every `api` request to the server authenticate him and then serve
  his request?
- Should I issue a `GUID` for every user at the signup, save it in
  their device and retrieve every time during an `api` request?

What other patterns are available and which are most efficient and secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First important note - don't store passwords anywhere - in your DB store it hashed and not in plain text.

In general, you want a flow where you create a session for the user and use that on 
subsequent requests. So, when your user logs in you validate the user/password hash combination and issue a session for the user. In your application you store the session and use it on future requests, until the user logs out or the session expires (usually you set an expiration to sessions).

There are also some generic auth flows you can look at, like [oauth2](http://oauth.net/2/).

I also strongly suggest going throw some documentation on authentication flows best practices.
You can start with these:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet
http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/some-best-practices-for-web-app-authentication/